# Raspberry pi waveshare7 inch touchscreem lineage os

Tags: touchscreen, internet

I'm recently using raspberry pi with lineage installed on it . When i connect to tv as monitor every thing is perfect. But when I'm using wave_Share 7 inch touchscreen.
Connection to internet failed.
What's the problem and how can i fix it

Comment: What have you done except for connecting the LCD display ? Have you read https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md ?

Comment: I didn't do anything .as i said when i connect raspberry pi to tv as monitor everything is ok an it connect to internet but when i connect hdmi cable to touch screen it doesnt connect to internet

Comment: Ok, What have you done to get it working ? This is NOT a forum for "I cant get it to work, please help me!", You need to first show what you have done to get it working. Have you been in touch with WaveShares support, have you searched for a solution ?